# Call a function when a user presses enter in an NSSearchField?

Tags: cocoa, text, return, enter, nssearchfield

I am surprised that I can't find the answer to this simple task.  I just want the user to type in text, press enter, and have the application know what s/he typed.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`NSSearchField` supports the action target mechanism, so simply hook it to a target/action. For instance, suppose you have the following action declared in your application delegate:

```
- (IBAction)searchAnswer:(id)sender;
```

In Interface Builder, ctrl-drag your search field to the application delegate object and choose the `searchAnswer:` action. In its implementation, use `-stringValue` to obtain the text typed by the user into the search field, e.g.

```
- (IBAction)searchAnswer:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"search answer: %@", [searchField stringValue]);
}
```

Note that by default the search field sends the action when the user pauses/stops typing, too. If you want it to send the action only when the user types Enter, choose the `Sends Whole Search String` checkbox in the search field attributes inspector window.

Comment: @Flafla2: Target/action is at a higher level than key or mouse events. A field may send its action even if the user has no Enter key, or no keyboard at all. A button may send its action even if the user has no mouse. Using target/action means you can receive the action regardless of what interface devices the user has or hasn't.